# Is there a tool (or npm package) that could help my visualize my React app components data flow?

Tags: web-apps, data-visualization, react

I would like to have a tool that would help me to visualize how my React components are interacting with themselves. Something that would show my which `state` is being owned by which component, what `props` it's receiving and passing along, what `context` it is providing and what `context` it is consuming. What each component is rendering. And so on.

I imagined that maybe there is a NPM package that does it and display in some sort of chart or diagram based on your code.

Or maybe a component design planning tool that is made for React apps or that has a specific template for React components dataflow visualization.

Is there such a thing?